# r use make.names() to rename columns

Tags: r

i'm using the make.names() column to create better column names, removing illegal symbols etc. how do I apply the new column names to the dataset?

this produces the vector of new column names:

```
names(data) %>% make.names()
```

i've tried these approaches to get the new column names to replace the old ones (these don't work the way I want):

```
names(data) %>%  make.names() <- data
names(data) %>%  make.names() <- names(data)
data <- names(data) %>%  make.names()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
names(data) <- names(data) %>%  make.names()
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
          set_names(make.names(names(.)))
```

Or with `rename_all`

```
data <- data %>%
          rename_all(~ make.names(.))
```

Comment: Or `df <- as_tibble(df, .name_repair = 'universal')`.